# Explode multiple columns to rows in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, explode

I have the below spark dataframe.

```
Name     age     subject        parts
xxxx     21      Maths,Physics  I
yyyy     22      English,French I,II
```

I am trying to explode the above dataframe in both subject and parts like below.

Expected output:

```
Name     age     subject        parts
xxxx     21      Maths          I
xxxx     21      Physics        I
yyyy     22      English        I
yyyy     22      English        II
yyyy     22      French         I
yyyy     22      French         II
```

I tried using array.zip for subject and parts and then tried to explode using the temp column, but I am getting null values in the place where there is only one part.

Is there a way to achieve this in Pyspark.

Comment: [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)

Comment: what is your schema ?

Comment: Name, age, subject and parts. All are string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did this by passing columns as list to a for loop and exploded the dataframe for every element in list

Comment: that's not really an answer... other people that will find your question cannot release on that simple phrase to understand what they're supposed to do in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use both [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) :

#### Data Sample

```py
df.show()
+----+---+--------------+-----+                                                 
|Name|age|       subject|parts|
+----+---+--------------+-----+
|xxxx| 21| Maths,Physics|    I|
|yyyy| 22|English,French| I,II|
+----+---+--------------+-----+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- parts: string (nullable = true)
```

#### Data Transformation

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "subject", F.explode(F.split("subject", ","))
).withColumn(
    "parts", F.explode(F.split("parts", ","))
).show()

+----+---+-------+-----+
|Name|age|subject|parts|
+----+---+-------+-----+
|xxxx| 21|  Maths|    I|
|xxxx| 21|Physics|    I|
|yyyy| 22|English|    I|
|yyyy| 22|English|   II|
|yyyy| 22| French|    I|
|yyyy| 22| French|   II|
+----+---+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can split them separately then join them back together

**Split subjects**

```py
df1 = (df
    .select('name', 'age', 'subject')
    .withColumn('subject', F.explode(F.split('subject', ',')))
)

# +----+---+-------+
# |name|age|subject|
# +----+---+-------+
# |xxxx| 21|  Maths|
# |xxxx| 21|Physics|
# |yyyy| 22|English|
# |yyyy| 22| French|
# +----+---+-------+
```

**Split parts**

```py
df2 = (df
    .select('name', 'age', 'parts')
    .withColumn('parts', F.explode(F.split('parts', ',')))
)

# +----+---+-----+
# |name|age|parts|
# +----+---+-----+
# |xxxx| 21|    I|
# |yyyy| 22|    I|
# |yyyy| 22|   II|
# +----+---+-----+
```

**Join back**

```py
df1.join(df2, on=['name', 'age'])

# +----+---+-------+-----+
# |name|age|subject|parts|
# +----+---+-------+-----+
# |xxxx| 21|  Maths|    I|
# |xxxx| 21|Physics|    I|
# |yyyy| 22|English|    I|
# |yyyy| 22|English|   II|
# |yyyy| 22| French|    I|
# |yyyy| 22| French|   II|
# +----+---+-------+-----+
```

Comment: the join will add a useless shuffle step that you can avoid by exploding directly within the same dataframe